# How to reference the exposed Google Cloud Endpoint programmatically?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, locust

I am new to Kubernetes and Google Cloud in general.

I created a cluster and then deployed a web application on it. Every time I do that, Google Cloud assigns to me a different endpoint that I can obtain running:

```
kubectl get service my-deployed-app-service
```

and checking the relative `EXTERNAL-IP` (for example, http://34.95.62.152:5001/).

Now if I want to reference that webapp (for example to run a Locust swarm), I have to manually check what IP I've been assigned every time. Is there a way to do that programmatically? I would think about an alias of the IP, or a way to obtain a static IP?

Comment: Unless I was writing an application, I would use parse the JSON output from `kubectl -ojson get service my-deployed-app-service` using [jq JSON processor](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/). Put the commands in a shell script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why do you say "unless I was writing an application"?

Comment: How do you deploy and redeploy your services on Kubernetes?

Comment: A script is a quick solution to solve a problem. An application is something that will be used long-term, provides additional features, and is written with a programming language. Writing code that interfaces with Kubernetes can be complicated. Even this simple problem can take many hours to hand code.